# MySQL Convert ROW_NUMBER() OVER PARTITION

Tags: mysql, sql-server

I'm trying to convert an MSSQL database to MySQL and my version is 5.7. I have hit a roadblock.

```
SELECT orderid, invs.[InvoiceID],  invs.[InvoiceDate],
invs.[InvoiceNumber], invs.[HasClientPaid],
ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION by orderid,invs.invoicenumber,HasClientpaid ORDER BY orderid) AS DistNum 
FROM InvoiceLineItems Ilt 
JOIN Invoices Invs ON Ilt.InvoiceID= invs.InvoiceID
```

Any help would be greatly appreciated. Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

MySQL will commence to suport window functions such as `row_number()` in version 8.x (*not yet production ready as at Oct 29 2017*), until then using @variables is a technique to mimic the effect:

```
SELECT
      @row_num :=IF(@prev_value=concat_ws('',orderid, invs.invoicenumber, HasClientpaid),@row_num+1,1)AS RowNumber
    , orderid
    , invs.[InvoiceID]
    , invs.[InvoiceDate]
    , invs.[InvoiceNumber]
    , invs.[HasClientPaid]
    , @prev_value := concat_ws('',orderid, invs.invoicenumber, HasClientpaid)
FROM InvoiceLineItems Ilt
JOIN Invoices Invs ON Ilt.InvoiceID = invs.InvoiceID
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row_num :=1,  @prev_value :=0) vars
ORDER BY
      orderid, invs.invoicenumber, HasClientpaid
;
```

You need to concatenate the 3 fields `orderid, invs.invoicenumber, HasClientpaid` to mimic your original partitioning, and the ordering will need to be by those 3 columns as well. The `ORDER BY` is essential for this to work, if you need some other final ordering use the above as a subquery.

Comment: why have that cross join? I know that subquery initializes those row_num and prev_value variables but why do it with a cross join?

Comment: The cross join simply adds the 2 new columns. Also note because it only has one row the cross join does not increase the total number of rows.

Comment: Thanks Paul, much appreciated!

Comment: By the way, in many older examples of this MySQL technique you may find that the subquery for the extra columns is just listed in the from clause but separated by a comma with no join conditions for that subquery in the where clause. That has the same effect as an explicit cross join, but I do NOT recommend mixing that ancient syntax with explicit joins. Far better IMHO to be explicit and show that one is using a cross join.

Comment: Very valid point!