# MySQL: Increment column by field

Tags: mysql, sql, increment

I am trying to create some sort of *list* of fruits. I want create a temporary column `increment_value` that takes the count of how much fruit has been inserted by type.

I have this **fruits** table:

```
+----------+------------+
| fruit_id | fruit_name | 
+----------+------------+
| 5        | Apple      | 
| 8        | Banana     | 
| 8        | Banana     | 
| 5        | Apple      | 
| 5        | Apple      | 
+----------+------------+
```

**Desired result:**

```
+----------+------------+-----------------+
| fruit_id | fruit_name | increment_value |
+----------+------------+-----------------+
| 5        | Apple      | 1               |
| 8        | Banana     | 1               |
| 8        | Banana     | 2               |
| 5        | Apple      | 2               |
| 5        | Apple      | 3               |
+----------+------------+-----------------+
```

I tried with dummy table but failed: [DEMO](https://www.db-fiddle.com/f/cfrhWey8oVKGK83XELJCsb/13)

How do I get the table I want?

Comment: Which MySQL version?

Comment: Why do you store several equal rows? Consider a count column instead.

Comment: @jarlh indifferent version. Better if 5.7

Comment: @jarlh I don't save the data like this, it's the result of a join

Comment: @AlbertoMoro on the contrary, the version matters *a lot*. Only MySQL 8.0 offers a real solution with [Window functions](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/window-function-descriptions.html) like ROW_NUMBER, RANK or DENSE_RANK. In all previous versions you have to use hacks, like incrementing a variable

Comment: So, that's what you are trying to do. And over there is what you have tried. Great. But what is the question?

Comment: I'm fine with the `row_number` too. More than anything else I need an idea to unlock me from this deadlock.

Comment: @AlbertoMoro check the window functions then. They don't work in any version before 8.0 though. Nor do CTEs, a feature other databases used for this job before they introduced window functions

Comment: You have no PRIMARY KEY. Fix that first.

Comment: Thank you @PanagiotisKanavos with that manual I was able to develop the query I needed.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use `row_number()`:

```
select f.*,
       row_number() over (partition by fruit_name order by fruit_name) as seqnum
from fruits f;
```

Note:  SQL tables and result sets represent *unordered* sets, so the ordering is indeterminate.  You can adjust the ordering by changing the `order by` clause.

Comment: ... which obviously only makes sense if there's something to order by

Comment: Thanks, with this answer I was able to develop the query I needed. If you need it below I put the solution for MySQL 5.7

Answer (score 0):

Thanks to @Gordon's reply. I taking inspiration from [this post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/46869355/mysql-convert-row-number-over-partition).
I wrote this for **MySQL 5.7**.

```
SELECT  
    fruits.*,
    @row_num :=IF(@prev_value= fruit_id, @row_num+1 , 1)AS RowNumber,
    @prev_value := fruit_id
FROM fruits
CROSS JOIN (SELECT @row_num :=1,  @prev_value :=0) vars
ORDER BY fruit_id
```

Thank you all for your help!

Answer (score -1):

you can simply do a group by query like:

```
SELECT fruit_id, fruit_name, SUM(fruit_id) as increment_value
FROM fruits
GROUP BY fruit_id;
```

Comment: Thanks for the help but this query is not what I was looking for